# Returning a formatted string in python

Tags: python

```
def compute_tax(gross_pay):
    tax = gross_pay * 0.15
    return "PHP {:,.2f}".format(tax)
```

I am trying to return the tax in a formatted string, but it generates an error `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'` Why does this happen? The gross_pay is float. I also tested this function using `pytest` and it worked fine. But when I run the program itself, it crashes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this error happening on the line:
```tax = gross_pay * 0.15``` 
If so, then you can fix this by making sure gross_pay is a floating-point number type.

Comment: *Look at the traceback message Python gives you* - it will tell you exactly where this function was called from, with `gross_pay` incorrectly being a string.

Comment: @BlueRobin, yes, it is a floating-point number. When I return it as a floating-point number, it doesn't generate an error. But I want the returning value to be a formatted string.

Comment: You need to give us enough code to reproduce the error. Using your function with a float like `compute_tax(10.56)` works just fine and returns the string `'PHP 1.58'`. Calling it with a string like `compute_tax('10.56')` produces the error you see.

Comment: @jasonharper, thank you, I figured it out now. The function for computing the gross_pay also returned a formatted string, hence the error.

Comment: @Mark, that is right. I didn't include the other function which computes the gross_pay and is returning a string.

Comment: How do you determine 0.15 of a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your other function is returning gross_pay as a string, you can always convert it to a float.

```
def compute_tax(gross_pay):
    gross_pay = float(gross_pay)
    tax = gross_pay * 0.15
    return "PHP {:,.2f}".format(tax)
```